# How to send an SMS message when a Webform is submitted?

Tags: 7, webforms

I am trying to have an SMS message sent when a form is submitted. The form is a quote request and I would like to send a simple message to my phone to alert me.

I have installed the [SMS Framework](https://www.drupal.org/project/smsframework) module and the [Clickatell](https://www.drupal.org/project/sms_clickatell) module. I have set up an account on Clickatell and have the necessary username, password, and api id.

I can send a message by pasting the url in my browser using the example on the Clickatell site but I don't know how to send a message when the quote request form is submitted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the "[Webform Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_rules)" module, you should be able to have the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module react on an event like "Webform submitted".

So create a custom rule using this Rules Event, and then add a Rules Action to send an SMS message, similar to what is shown in the video  tutorial "[How to send SMS messages](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=dqkOcz_8I4U)" (starting from around 5:25).

Comment: This worked great! What an easy solution to my problem. Thanks, Pierre.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand, you need to make a call to Clickatell API in order to send a message, and you're asking how to do this in the background.

You need to use the [`drupal_http_request()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_http_request/7) function. Here's an example:

```
$response = drupal_http_request(YOUR_API_ENDPOINT, $options);
if ($response->code == 200) {
  // Everything was OK.
}
else {
  // An error occurred. You can log this, or process further.
}
```

Hope this helps.