# How to alert users when new content is added via email and/or text message?

Tags: 7, users

I have a membership Drupal 7 website and I'd like to automatically alert users via their email address and/or text message to their cell phone when new content is added? I'd also like to give registered users the ability to select/change these communication preferences.

Is there any Drupal way/technique that can provide this functionality?

Comment: any feedback about my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at my answer to "[How to send an SMS message when a Webform is submitted?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/192854/how-to-send-an-sms-message-when-a-webform-is-submitted/192860#192860)", which is a variation of your question here. It describes how you can use the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module to get this to work. In your case just use a Rules Event like "after saving new content", and optionally add some appropriate Rules Conditions to better fit your exact needs.